# Entity Framework 4: Are Objects Automatically Attached?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have noticed that for some reason my objects that are neither coming from a query nor are added with ObjectContext.MySet.AddObject(myObj) are somehow attached to the ObjectContext.

```
foreach (SomeClass someObject in someSet)
            {
                //it says an object is added...
                MessageBox.Show(someObject.EntityState.ToString());

                foreach (SomeProperty someProperty in someObject.SomeProperty)
                {
                    //type is given above   
                    someObject.someProperty = type;
                }

                var existing = from o in db.SomeObjectSet
                               where o.Name == someObject.Name
                               select o;

                if (existing.Count() == 0)
                {
                    db.SomeObjectSet.AddObject(someObject);
                }
                //apparently I have to detach them because 
                //they are already attached for some reason
                else
                {
                    db.Detach(vulnerability);
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Please, note that someSet doesn't come from a database it comes from a different type of source, say a text file.

Normally, I'd never need to detach an object because it's not attached, but not in this case apparently.

Comment: What is `vulnerability`? Is there any relation between `someObjects`?

Comment: What is `SomeObjectSet`?

Comment: can you please be clearer about what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you associate an object with another object that has already been added to the context, it will also be pending for insertion next time GetChanges is called (which is part of SubmitChanges).  This is based on my experience with LINQ to SQL; I assume entity framework is similar.

Comment: @BlueMongMN, thank you! I found some other place in the code where I added an association that caused my *parent* objects to become attached to the context.

Answer (score 0):

[No; objects are not created attached by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx). It is entirely acceptable (and normal, in ASP.NET programs) to have multiple object contexts per process.

I'd check other places in your code to see why the entities are attached.